# Spliting / copy an agent - making an exact copy

Tags: java, split, anylogic

I want to make a copy of an agent using the `Split` block. The problem is that the Copy does not have any of the parameters that the Original has.

Is there a way to make a perfect Copy of an Original agent? `new Agent()` in the `New agent (copy)` Split block does not work.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. Why would you want a perfect copy anyway?

I typically want copies that are *almost* perfect copies. So I set all copy parameters to the parent values using `agent.set_MyParam(original.MyParam)`.

Sometimes, I also copy over some core variables and data structures, but that is it.

Comment: I am doing DES. Part of the problem is that if an agent is ‘busy’ doing something, it is busy doing that specific thing and nothing else. Having a perfect double, I can create a different path that the Copy can do while the Original is busy doing its thing.

Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: not sure that splitting would be the best approach here. What real-world application are you modelling and how does that behavior come into play there?

Comment: I am modeling an exam room (multiple ones). A patient comes in (serviced by) with the nurse; meanwhile, a doctor comes. If the patient is busy with the nurse, s/he cannot call the doctor (I am doing DES, not Agent based). While busy with the doctor, the patient can release the nurse; 5 minutes later, calls her back. The only way that I figured to solve this is by doing an exact copy of the patient (placed in the same room) where one deals with the nurse, one with the doctor. Basically, there are parallel processes that an actor needs to do through… Which other way did you have in mind?

Comment: @AlexW. splitting is not at all the right approach for that application, I suggest you ask a new question on stackoverflow explaining the problem you are trying to solve with more detail... I think this is a case where you have to release and immediately seize the same resource for a different activity and there are some techniques to do that

Comment: fully agree with Felipe: do not copy-split agents. Very rarely (if ever) should you need to do that...